# How to define a factor as being above or below its median in R?

Tags: r, statistics

So I need to create a factor that defines my 'alt' variable (altitude) as being above or below its median.

I know it should follow this basic shape of creating something new:

```
conservation$alt.factor <- conservation$alt (..????...)
```

But I'm just struggling with that last bit.

There must be simple command out there!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. `dput(head(consercation, 10))` should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ifelse()`:

```
conservation$alt.factor <- factor(
  ifelse(conservation$alt < median(conservation$alt, na.rm = TRUE), 1, 
   ifelse(conservation$alt > median(conservation$alt, na.rm = TRUE), 2, NA)), 
 1:2, labels = c("below", "above"))
```

Beware, this setup sets all rows with `conservation$alt == median(conservation$alt)` as `NA`. If this is not wanted, just change the last parameter in the `ifelse`-statement to something else.

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly straightforward to do. Find values above calculated median and assign some new value to a new variable. This is easy to explain in code:

```
set.seed(357)
xy <- data.frame(original = rnorm(100))

above.median <- xy$original > median(xy$original) # find values above the median
xy$new[above.median] <- "above" # to those that are above, assign "above"
xy$new[!above.median] <- "below" # notice the exclamation mark which negates the statement
head(xy)

    original   new
1 -1.2411173 below
2 -0.5832050 below
3  0.3947471 above
4  1.5042111 above
5  0.7667997 above
6  0.3174604 above

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(xy, aes(x = original, y = 1, color = new)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]